# statsmodels ARMAResults.predict start index after length of training data returns incorrect array

Tags: statsmodels, predict, moving-average, autoregressive-models

http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResults.predict

I am using `statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMAResults.predict` to determine the forecasted values of an ARIMA model. The function returns the correct array of values when I call it with a start index that is within the training data. However, if I use a start index that is outside the training data, the returned array, for some reason, is totally incorrect.

Original code, with `start=1000` and `end=1481`. `r` is an `ARMAResult` from a previously fitted model with 481 data points.

Note: the `end-1` is because calling predict returns an array that includes the prediction at the index of `end`.

```
p = r.predict(start, end-1)
print(end-start)
print(len(p))
```

From this code, I get the following output:

```
481
1000
```

I fixed the problem by slicing the list instead with this code.

```
p = r.predict(0, end)[start:end]
print(end-start)
print(len(p))
```

Output:

```
481
481
```

My question is, why does this happen? My `end` can be way outside of the length of the original dataset and `predict` returns perfectly, but even if the `start` index is the first number outside of the length of the dataset the array returned is far too long and the numbers are different. My guess would have been that it has something to do with how the data needs the previous values to be calculated before the next ones can, but the values are already part of the `ARMAResult` object, and I am totally stuck.